# BEP20 Token : Gas estimate failed, trying eth_call to extract error

Tags: solidity, erc-20, gas-estimate, binance-smart-chain

I'm new to Solidity and I've successfully built a BEP20 smart contract using Solidity version 8.19. The contract includes several features such as pausable, ownable, blacklist, fee division among three wallets, exclusion/inclusion options for fees, and limits on maximum tokens and tokens per address.

However, I'm encountering some challenges after deploying the smart contract in Bsc testnet. Firstly, I'm having issues with gas fee estimation during swap transactions (buying/selling) :

> Gas estimate failed, trying eth_call to extract error

Additionally, instead of the expected SwapExactTokens method, a Multicall method is being used during swaps (It uses the Pancakeswap SmartRouter but the gas fees cost more then a simple SwapExactTokens... Method). Furthermore, the fee division functionality is not working as intended even if the logic for me is clear and clean.

It would be great if anyone can help with that please.

Here is my smart contract :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/BEP20/IBEP20.sol";
import "./SafeBEP20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/BEP20/extensions/IBEP20Metadata.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/Pausable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Address.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Context.sol";
import "@pancakeswap/pancake-swap-lib/contracts/interfaces/IPancakeFactory.sol";
import "@pancakeswap/pancake-swap-lib/contracts/interfaces/IPancakeRouter01.sol";
import "@pancakeswap/pancake-swap-lib/contracts/interfaces/IPancakeRouter02.sol";

contract MTK4 is Context, IBEP20, IBEP20Metadata, Ownable, Pausable {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    using Address for address;
    using SafeBEP20 for IBEP20;

    mapping(address => uint256) private _balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) private _allowances;
    mapping(address => bool) private _isBlacklisted;
    mapping(address => bool) private _isExcludedFromFee; // New mapping declaration
    mapping(address => bool) private _isExcludedFromMaxTokens;

    uint256 private _totalSupply;
    string private _name;
    string private _symbol;

    uint256 public gasLimit = 500000; // Set an initial gas limit for estimation
    address public teamWallet;
    address public reserveWallet;
    address public holdersWallet;
    uint256 public reserveFee = 300; // 3%
    uint256 public teamFee = 300; // 3%
    uint256 public holdersFee = 300; // 3%
    uint256 public maxTokensPerAddress;
    address private constant pancakeRouterAddress = 0xD99D1c33F9fC3444f8101754aBC46c52416550D1;

    IPancakeRouter02 public pancakeRouter;
    address public pancakePair;

    constructor() {
        _name = "MTK4";
        _symbol = "MTK4";
        _totalSupply = 1000000000 * 10 ** 18; // 1 billion tokens
        _balances[msg.sender] = _totalSupply;

        // Set up PancakeSwap v2 router and pair
        // Mainnet 
        // Factory : 0xBCfCcbde45cE874adCB698cC183deBcF17952812
        // Router : 0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E
        // TestNet
        // Factory : 0x6725F303b657a9451d8BA641348b6761A6CC7a17
        // Router : 0xD99D1c33F9fC3444f8101754aBC46c52416550D1
        pancakeRouter = IPancakeRouter02(pancakeRouterAddress);
        pancakePair = IPancakeFactory(pancakeRouter.factory()).createPair(address(this), pancakeRouter.WETH());

        teamWallet = 0x12357890...; 
        reserveWallet = 0x12357890...; 
        holdersWallet = 0x12357890...; 

        // Initialize maximum tokens per address (default to 1% of total supply)
        maxTokensPerAddress = _totalSupply.mul(5).div(500);

        emit Transfer(address(0), _msgSender(), _totalSupply);

        _isExcludedFromFee[owner()] = true;
        _isExcludedFromFee[address(this)] = true;
        _isExcludedFromFee[pancakeRouterAddress] = true;
        _isExcludedFromFee[teamWallet] = true;
        _isExcludedFromFee[reserveWallet] = true;
        _isExcludedFromFee[holdersWallet] = true;

        _isExcludedFromMaxTokens[owner()] = true;
        _isExcludedFromMaxTokens[address(this)] = true;
        _isExcludedFromMaxTokens[pancakeRouterAddress] = true;
        _isExcludedFromMaxTokens[teamWallet] = true;
        _isExcludedFromMaxTokens[reserveWallet] = true;
        _isExcludedFromMaxTokens[holdersWallet] = true;
    }
    receive() external payable {}

    function name() public view override returns (string memory) {
        return _name;
    }

    function symbol() public view override returns (string memory) {
        return _symbol;
    }

    function decimals() public pure override returns (uint8) {
        return 18;
    }

    function totalSupply() public view override returns (uint256) {
        return _totalSupply;
    }

    function balanceOf(address account) public view override returns (uint256) {
        if (_isBlacklisted[account]) {
            return 0;
        }
        return _balances[account];
    }

    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) public override whenNotPaused returns (bool) {

        // uint256 currentAllowance = _allowances[sender][_msgSender()];
        // require(amount <= currentAllowance, "Transfer amount exceeds allowance");

        _transfer(_msgSender(), recipient, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view override returns (uint256) {
        return _allowances[owner][spender];
    }

    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) public override whenNotPaused returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint256 amount
    ) public override whenNotPaused returns (bool) {
        _transfer(sender, recipient, amount);

        uint256 currentAllowance = _allowances[sender][_msgSender()];
        require(currentAllowance >= amount, "BEP20: transfer amount exceeds allowance");
        _approve(sender, _msgSender(), currentAllowance - amount);

        return true;
    }

    function increaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 addedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, _allowances[_msgSender()][spender] + addedValue);
        return true;
    }

    function decreaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 subtractedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
        uint256 currentAllowance = _allowances[_msgSender()][spender];
        require(currentAllowance >= subtractedValue, "BEP20: decreased allowance below zero");
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, currentAllowance - subtractedValue);

        return true;
    }

    function _approve(
        address owner,
        address spender,
        uint256 amount
    ) private {
        require(owner != address(0), "BEP20: approve from the zero address");
        require(spender != address(0), "BEP20: approve to the zero address");

        _allowances[owner][spender] = amount;
        emit Approval(owner, spender, amount);
    }

    function _transfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount
    ) private whenNotPaused {
        require(from != address(0), "BEP20: transfer from the zero address");
        require(to != address(0), "BEP20: transfer to the zero address");
        require(amount > 0, "Transfer amount must be greater than zero");
        require(!_isBlacklisted[from] && !_isBlacklisted[to], "Address is blacklisted");
        require(_balances[from] >= amount, "Insufficient Balance");
        uint256 reserveAmount;
        uint256 teamAmount;
        uint256 holdersAmount;
        uint256 transferAmount;

        if (!_isExcludedFromMaxTokens[from] && !_isExcludedFromMaxTokens[to]) {
            require(amount.add(_balances[to]) <= maxTokensPerAddress, "Transfer amount exceeds the maximum allowed tokens per address");
        }

        bool isContractExempt = (from == address(this) || to == address(this));

        if (!isContractExempt && !_isExcludedFromFee[from] && !_isExcludedFromFee[to]) {
            // Calculate fees
            (uint256 reserveAmount, uint256 teamAmount, uint256 holdersAmount, uint256 transferAmount) = calculateFees(amount);

            _balances[from] = _balances[from].sub(amount, "Insufficient Balance");
            _balances[to] = _balances[to].add(transferAmount);

            // Transfer fees to respective wallets
            transferFees(from, reserveAmount, teamAmount, holdersAmount);

            emit Transfer(from, to, transferAmount);
        } else {
            // If either the sender or the receiver is excluded from the fee, perform a standard token transfer
            _balances[from] = _balances[from].sub(amount, "Insufficient Balance");
            _balances[to] = _balances[to].add(amount);
            emit Transfer(from, to, amount);
        }
    }
    function calculateFees(uint256 amount) private view returns (uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256) {
        uint256 reserveAmount;
        uint256 teamAmount;
        uint256 holdersAmount;
        uint256 transferAmount;

        // Calculate the reserve fee amount
        reserveAmount = amount.mul(reserveFee).div(10000); // Dividing by 10000 to convert from basis points to decimal
        // Calculate the team fee amount
        teamAmount = amount.mul(teamFee).div(10000); // Dividing by 10000 to convert from basis points to decimal
        // Calculate the holders fee amount
        holdersAmount = amount.mul(holdersFee).div(10000); // Dividing by 10000 to convert from basis points to decimal
        // Calculate the transfer amount after deducting the holders fee, reserve fee, and team fee
        transferAmount = amount.sub(reserveAmount).sub(teamAmount).sub(holdersAmount);

        return (reserveAmount, teamAmount, holdersAmount, transferAmount);
    }

    function transferFees(address from, uint256 reserveAmount, uint256 teamAmount, uint256 holdersAmount) private {
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = address(this);
        path[1] = pancakeRouter.WETH();
        uint256 teamTransferAmount = teamAmount;

        require(address(this).balance > gasLimit, "Insufficient BNB balance for gas");

        // Swap team fee tokens to BNB and transfer to smart contract
        if (teamAmount > 1000) {
            // Deduct 0.001 BNB from the teamAmount
            swapFees(from, address(this), 1000);
            teamTransferAmount = teamAmount.sub(1000);
        }
        else {
            swapFees(from, address(this), teamTransferAmount);
            teamTransferAmount = 0;
        }

        if (teamTransferAmount > 0) {
            swapFees(from, teamWallet, teamTransferAmount);
            _balances[teamWallet] = _balances[teamWallet].add(teamTransferAmount);
        }

        swapFees(from, reserveWallet, reserveAmount);
        swapFees(from, holdersWallet, holdersAmount);

        _balances[reserveWallet] = _balances[reserveWallet].add(reserveAmount);
        _balances[holdersWallet] = _balances[holdersWallet].add(holdersAmount);
    }

    function swapFees(address from, address wallet, uint256 amount) private {
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = address(this);
        path[1] = pancakeRouter.WETH();
        require(address(this).balance > gasLimit, "Insufficient BNB balance for gas");

        // Swap tokens to BNB and transfer to the specified wallet
        pancakeRouter.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
            amount,
            0, // Accept any amount of BNB
            path,
            wallet,
            block.timestamp
        );
        emit Transfer(from, wallet, amount);
    }

    function excludeFromFee(address account) external onlyOwner() {
        require(account != address(0), "Invalid address");
        require(!_isExcludedFromFee[account], "Account is already excluded in fees");
        _isExcludedFromFee[account] = true;
    }

    function includeInFee(address account) external onlyOwner() {
        require(account != address(0), "Invalid address");
        require(_isExcludedFromFee[account], "Account is already included in fees");
        _isExcludedFromFee[account] = false;
    }

    function setMaxTokensPerAddress(uint256 maxTokens) external onlyOwner() {
        require(maxTokens <= 100, "Percentage value must be between 0 and 100");
        maxTokensPerAddress = _totalSupply.mul(maxTokens).div(100);
    }

    function blacklistAddress(address account) external onlyOwner() {
        require(account != address(0), "Invalid address");
        require(!_isBlacklisted[account], "Account is already blacklisted");
        _isBlacklisted[account] = true;
    }

    function unblacklistAddress(address account) external onlyOwner() { 
        require(account != address(0), "Invalid address");
        require(_isBlacklisted[account], "Account is not blacklisted");
        _isBlacklisted[account] = false;
    }
    function getOwner() external view override returns (address) {
        return owner();
    }
    function setGasLimit(uint256 newGasLimit) external onlyOwner {
        require(newGasLimit <= 3000000, "Gas limit exceeds maximum value");
        gasLimit = newGasLimit;
    }
    function setTeamWallet(address newWallet) external onlyOwner {
        require(newWallet != address(0), "BEP20: reserve wallet is the zero address");
        teamWallet = newWallet;
    }

    function setReserveWallet(address newWallet) external onlyOwner {
        require(newWallet != address(0), "BEP20: reserve wallet is the zero address");
        reserveWallet = newWallet;
    }
    function setHoldersWallet(address newWallet) external onlyOwner {
        require(newWallet != address(0), "BEP20: reserve wallet is the zero address");
        holdersWallet = newWallet;
    }

    function setReserveFee(uint256 fee) external onlyOwner {
        require(fee <= 500, "BEP20: reserve fee too high"); // Reserve fee cannot exceed 5%
        reserveFee = fee;
    }

    function setTeamFee(uint256 fee) external onlyOwner {
        require(fee <= 500, "BEP20: team fee too high"); // Team fee cannot exceed 5%
        teamFee = fee;
    }
    function setHoldersFee(uint256 fee) external onlyOwner {
        require(fee <= 500, "BEP20: holders fee too high"); // Team fee cannot exceed 5%
        holdersFee = fee;
    }

    function rescueTokens(address tokenAddress, uint256 tokenBalance) external onlyOwner {
        require( tokenBalance > 0, "tokenBalance have to be greater then zero");
        IBEP20(tokenAddress).safeTransfer(owner(), tokenBalance);
    }

    function rescueBNB() external onlyOwner {
        require(address(this).balance > 0, "Insufficient contract balance");
        payable(owner()).transfer(address(this).balance);
    }

    function excludeFromMaxTokens(address account) external onlyOwner() {
        require(account != address(0), "Invalid address");
        require(!_isExcludedFromMaxTokens[account], "Account is already excluded from maximum tokens restriction");
        _isExcludedFromMaxTokens[account] = true;
    }
    
    function includeInMaxTokens(address account) external onlyOwner() {
        require(account != address(0), "Invalid address");
        require(_isExcludedFromMaxTokens[account], "Account is already excluded from maximum tokens restriction");
        _isExcludedFromMaxTokens[account] = false;
    }

    function pause() public onlyOwner {
        require(!paused(), "Contract is already paused");
        _pause();
    }

    function unpause() public onlyOwner {
        require(paused(), "Contract is not paused");
        _unpause();
    }
}
```